# Docker container: pip is not found even though I have set the PATH during building

Tags: docker, path, pip, anaconda, dockerfile

I am new to docker container and I want to build an image with basic environment. Here is part of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:10.0-cudnn7-devel-ubuntu18.04

ARG CTAGS_DIR=~/tools/ctags
ARG RIPGREP_DIR=~/tools/ripgrep
ARG ANACONDA_DIR=~/tools/anaconda
ARG NVIM_DIR=~/tools/nvim
ARG NVIM_CONFIG_DIR=~/.config/nvim

# Install common dev tools
RUN apt-get update --allow-unauthenticated \
    && apt-get install --allow-unauthenticated -y git curl autoconf pkg-config zsh

# Install anaconda
COPY ./packages/Anaconda3-2019.07-Linux-x86_64.sh /tmp/anaconda.sh
RUN chmod u+x /tmp/anaconda.sh \
    && bash /tmp/anaconda.sh -b -p ${ANACONDA_DIR} \
    && rm /tmp/anaconda.sh
ENV PATH=${ANACONDA_DIR}/bin:$PATH
# RUN echo $PATH && ls -l /root/tools/anaconda/bin|grep pip
RUN echo $PATH && ls -l ~/tools/anaconda/bin|grep pip

# Python packages
RUN pip install pynvim jedi pylint
```

The build process fails at the pip install step complaining that

> /bin/sh: 1: pip: not found
>   The command '/bin/sh -c pip install pynvim jedi pylint' returned a non-zero code: 127

But the output of command

```
RUN echo $PATH && ls -l ~/tools/anaconda/bin|grep pip
```

is the following

```
~/tools/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/nvidia/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root      231 Sep 28 08:19 pip
```

which suggests that PATH is set and pip is foundable. I am not sure what is the problem here. 
The only explanation is that PATH is set but is not correctly set. I do not know why.

Can someone experience explain what happened? What is wrong with my Dockerfile?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see pip in the base image you used in your Dockerfile, you can check the offical [Dockerfile](https://gitlab.com/nvidia/container-images/cuda/blob/master/dist/ubuntu18.04/10.1/runtime/cudnn7/Dockerfile), nor in the base image of nvidia/cuda, you can check the base image too  [10.0-cudnn7-devel-ubuntu18.04](https://gitlab.com/nvidia/container-images/cuda/blob/master/dist/ubuntu18.04/10.1/base/Dockerfile.)

Installed pip and then try

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:10.0-cudnn7-devel-ubuntu18.04
RUN apt update && apt install python3-pip -y
RUN pip3 --version
```

Comment: I have installed anaconda. Pip is shipped with Anaconda. The `ls` command also shows that `pip` is indeed installed (see the post).

Comment: Then you call pip from that directory,  I'm not sure Anaconda have pip but the base image is missing

Comment: The output of `RUN echo $PATH && ls -l ~/tools/anaconda/bin|grep pip` clearly show that pip is installed. I just can not call pip.

Comment: So its looking in this path ~/tools/anaconda/bin, then use the same path to call pip or create soft link

Comment: It seems that tilde `~` is not expanded to home directory inside a container. Tilde `~` works in normal shell if I do not include the PATH double quotes.

Comment: Yes it might be the case, did double quotes worked?

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: So call the pip with absolute path